# std::size() from iterator library won't work on C-style array passed to function

Tags: c++, arrays

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>

void count(int foo[])
{
    int dSize;
    dSize=std::size(foo); //No matching function for call to 'size' 
    std::cout<<dSize<<std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    int arr[5]={0,0,0,0,0};
    count(arr);
    return 0;
}
```

Hi, I'm trying to run this code, but it give me this error. The std::size function work perfectly whenever I'm not passing the array to the count function, like this:

```
std::size(arr);// this work fine
```

is it because of when you pass this to a function the array decay to a pointer?

Comment: ......yes.......

Comment: That's affirmative.

Comment: `void count(int foo[])` is the same function as `void count(int * foo)`

Comment: Basically, don't try to use C++ on C constructs. Use it on C++ constructs....

Comment: Prefer to use `std::array`

Comment: ...or `std::vector`, depending on your needs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> is it because of when you pass this to a function the array decay to a pointer?

Almost. More accurately, it is because you declared that the function argument is a pointer. `std::size` only works with containers (or anything that has member function `size`) and arrays. A pointer is neither of those.

Answer (score 2):

> is it because of when you pass this to a function the array decay to a pointer?

**Yes.**

Looking at the documentation of [`std::size()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/size):

It can have one of the following signatures:

```cpp
//(1)   (since C++17)
template <class C>
constexpr auto size(const C& c) -> decltype(c.size());

//(2)   (since C++20)   
template <class C>
constexpr auto ssize(const C& c)
    -> std::common_type_t<std::ptrdiff_t,
                          std::make_signed_t<decltype(c.size())>>;

//(3) (since C++17)
template <class T, std::size_t N>
constexpr std::size_t size(const T (&array)[N]) noexcept;

//(4) (since C++20)
template <class T, std::ptrdiff_t N>
constexpr std::ptrdiff_t ssize(const T (&array)[N]) noexcept;
```

As you can see, none of them takes a pointer.